# Swap two strings in an array, Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem swapping two strings in my array. Let's say Array[0] is "Daniel" and Array[1] is "Paul", how do you go about switching them?

This is my code and it just throws a bunch of errors at me.

```
public void swap()
{
    String name1;
    String name2;
    String temp1;
    String temp2;
    System.out.print("\nWhich person would you like to swap?: ");
    name1 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Who are they swapping with?: ");
    name2 = input.next();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if(seats[i] == name1)
        {
            temp1 = name1;
            temp2 = name2;
            name1 = temp2;
            name2 = temp1;  
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(name1 + " and " + name2 + " have been swapped.\n");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nowayz Its not duplicate, please check the link there the question was related to `Javascript` but here the question is asked for `Java` language.

Comment: @startrak if my answer is helpful you can select my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(seats[i] == name1)`// this is wrong

when you compare Strings you should use `.equals` or `.EqualsIgnoreCase`

```
if(seats[i].equals(name1){
        temp1 = name1;
        temp2 = name2;
        name1 = temp2;
        name2 = temp1;  

//you can directly do this to swap
  //  temp = name1;
  //  name1 = name2;
  //  name2 = temp;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

```
temp1 = name1;
name1 = name2;
name2 = temp1;
```

should do it.
assuming u have initialised `string[] seats = {"Paul","Sam"};` with atleast 10 strings

and

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I think that works, but now when I try to print out the array it's giving me a "NullPointerException." When I want to print out the array, I want it to display the position in the array, then the name. And if a slot in the array is null, don't print anything. But it just gives me that exception error.